# Zotero + zotfile configuration, preserving the folder - subfolders structure

Tags: zotero

I was recommended to move from Mendeley to Zotero given that open source nature, and I did it. I work with Google drive storage, using one computer as base. In my bibliography structure, as most of people I work with i.e Genes which contains multiple subfolders according different genes, or lipid metabolism and hanging from there multiple subfolders

[image]

The Zotfile plugin enables to save articles in Zotero without saving them in the software storage (which is 300Mb). However as far as I've seen you need to set your Custom Location and Source Folder in one folder. Isn't it possible to preserve the structure of bibliography storage in Google Drive (G: with folders and subfolders hanging)
To clarify, I'm making reference to the step of Manage Attachments>Rename and Move, when the PDF is linked to the specifed folder

[image]